# Search for same digits in a number variable

Tags: python

If i have a number like:

```
1234567899
or
1999234567
or
1294597890
or
9234967890
```

I want to print "Test" whenever a digit appears more than once in the number.

Comment: You want to check if an integer contains a 9 in base 10?

Comment: Not only contains a 9, but contains multiple same digit. And only base on 10, so yes.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yeah i have tried some method like looping in the looping for checking one by one, but using set() for the solution - i never thought about it. So, sorry if it's actually duplicated question but I think it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast the integer to a string, this will allow to process its characters one by one. You can then use a `set` to keep track of seen digits.

For very big numbers, this will be more efficient than counting digits as you are assured it will always return before the eleventh digit.

```
def has_duplicate_digit(x):
    digits = set()

    for d in str(x):
        if d in digits:
            return True
        digits.add(d)
    return False
```

### Examples

```
print(has_duplicate_digit(123)) # False
print(has_duplicate_digit(11)) # True
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!